# Dataflow streaming mode and assigning into single window

Tags: streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Let's say that we have a dataflow/apache beam streaming pipeline reading from PubSub and writing into BQ.
In the pipeline we have a fix time 30 seconds window.

Pipeline reads 1000 pubsubs messages, all with exactly the same pubsub `publish_time`/event time.
999 of those elements have been processed in 1 seconds each, but this one single element is being processed for 1 hour.
What will happen? 999 elements will be hold and wait for this problematic one? All of them are assigned to the same window, so in fact this problematic element will be some kind of bottleneck, blocking all the 999 others?

Comment: Do you currently following a documentation?

Comment: Yes, but still I have some doubts and that is why I wrote this post.

Comment: It very much depends on how you define your window and how are you handling your late data (which would be the 1000th element in your example). Check for example [this article](https://github.com/griscz/beam-college/blob/main/day2/B1_Beam_College_Advanced_Windows_and_Triggers_a_practical_guide_v0_9_0.ipynb).